# Laravel Vue JS live event broadcasting with pusher

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, pusher

I want to make an application in which the use makes a request and the admin receives a notification about it. I am using Laravel 5.5 and Vue JS with pusher and laravel echo. I have installed everything.
The problem is when the user submits the request it still does not show the update with refreshing.
Here's some of my code:
RequestFiled.php (which is the event)

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Request;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class RequestFiled implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $request;
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->user = $request->user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('notifications');
    }
}
```

In the RequestsController.php file I have this alongside with the code which enters in the DB:

```
//Event
            broadcast(new RequestFiled($userRequest));
```

Notifications.vue:

```
<template>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
            <span class="notification">{{ notifications.length }}</span>
            <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Notifications</p>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li v-for="notification in notifications">
                <a href="#">{{ notification.message }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                notifications: []
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            this.getNotifications(),

            Echo.channel('notifications')
                .listen('RequestFiled', (e) => {
                    console.log('user made a request')
                })
        },
        methods: {
            getNotifications: function() {
                let app = this

                axios.get('/api/notifications')
                    .then(function(response) {
                        app.notifications = response.data
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

channels.php:

```
Broadcast::channel('notifications', function ($user, $request) {
    return true;
});
```

On the notifications page which listens for the RequestFiled event nothing happens when the request is stored in the database but nothing happens live. Only when I refresh the page. It shows no errors.

Comment: Have you set `BROADCAST_DRIVER` to `pusher` in `.env`?

Comment: @craig_h Yes I did

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. If you add `Pusher.log = function (message) { window.console.log(message); };` to `app.js` you should get some details about what's going on in your developer console.

Comment: You also need to update your bootstrap.js file. Uncomment import Echo and update your pusher key.